# Python3 & SQLite3 JSON api calls

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, json-api

I'm starting my Python journey with a particular project in mind;
The title explains what I'm trying to do (make json api calls with python3.6 and sqlite3). I'm working on a mac.
My question is whether or not this setup is possible? Or if I should use MySQL, PostgreSQL or MongoDB?
If it is possible, am I going to have to use any 3rd party software to make it run?

Sorry if this is off topic, I'm new to SO and I've been trying to research this via google and so far no such luck.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.6 and sqlite both work on a Mac; whether your json api calls will depends on what service you are trying to make calls to (unless you are writing a server that services such calls, in which case you are fine).

Any further recommendations are either a) off topic for SO or b) dependent on what you want to do with these technologies.

Comment: So i've spent most of my day researching how to create and manage a database in SQLite. Practiced with a couple basic ones. Even purchased my first tool (SQLiteManager4) which I've found to be very helpful in both making the process of creating databases easier as well as being a great learning tool as it displays the code used simultaneously with the users actions. Feeling more confident on that score. I am having issues on the JSON front however, I'm planning on using my database as a cache and I'm not sure how to go about populating my database with the external api.

Comment: Don't worry this can be closed. Although I wanted to learn python with this project I switched to node.js (using atom) to make this simpler and got things working. Considering this post has just over 20 views in less than a day (honestly don't know how many of them were mine!) if anyone would like to know how I went about doing this just ask and I'll post the method for you.